# Get values to a dropdownlist associated to the UserId

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have an application that basically controls the expenses and income of a person, and an expense is associated with a type of expenditure, these types of expenditure can be created by the user and must differ from user to user.
Exemplifying best for the types of expenditure can have various options available and I can only pick one, this was implemented through a dropdownlist.
What was intended that each user had their types of expenditure and that they were different from each other, what I have is the following:

Model Expenses:

```
public class Expense
{
    public int TipeExpenseId { get; set; }

    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição da Despesa")]
    [Required]
    public string ExpenseDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    [Required]
    public decimal ExpenseValue { get; set; }

    public int PayementTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public ExpenseTipe ExpenseTipe { get; set; }

    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comentário")]
    public string Coment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

}
```

Model TipeExpense:

```
public int ExpenseTipeId { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Tipo de Despesa")]
[Required]
public string ExpenseTipeName { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

I want to get all the ExpenseTipe related to the user that Create it, i think i need to do something in the linq query, to not get all the list of tipe of expenses, but just the expenses that have the same Id as the User but i dont know how to do it in the Linq query, here is my controller that fills the DropDown list.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DespesaId,TipoDespesaId,DespesaDescricao,DespesaValor,TipoPagamentoId,Data,Comentario")] Despesa despesa)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        despesa.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Despesas.Add(despesa);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.TipoDespesaId = new SelectList(db.TipoDespesas, "TipoDespesaId", "TipoDespesaNome", despesa.TipoDespesaId);
    ViewBag.TipoPagamentoId = new SelectList(db.TipoPagamentos, "TipoPagamentoId", "TipoPagamentoNome", despesa.TipoPagamentoId);
    return View(despesa);
}
```

**I think i need a where condition in the viewBag but dont know how to do it :S**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a where clause to your db.TipoDespesas.

```
db.TipoDespesas.where(x=> x.applicationUserid == UserId)
```

Comment: Yeah i actually solved it few moments ago, and wanted to post it here, i thaught it was harder then that, maybe i complicate a lot wat is simple to do :D, but thanks